# Mvc 3 conditional HTML

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, conditional-statements

The following code works:

```
  @if ( Model.document.usesNumericRevision )
            {
             <tr>
                    <th>Major Revision</th>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.document.documentStatus.documentRevision.MajorRevision )</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                    <th>Minor Revision</th>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.document.documentStatus.documentRevision.MinorRevision )</td>
              </tr>
            }
        else
            { 
             <tr>
                <th>Alphanumeric Revision</th>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.document.documentStatus.documentRevision.Revision )</td>
            </tr>
            }
```

Depending on the value of usesNumericRevision the appropriate HTML will display.  But if the user checks / unchecks the checkbox, the view will not update.  Is there a way to update the view without going back to the server?

Answer (score 0):

The condition statement in the view is executed on the server and sent to the client. You need to use JavaScript to do it client side without going back to the sever.

Answer (score 0):

Yes... but you need some jQuery to do the client side stuff.

```
<div id="NumericRevision">
 <tr>
   <th>Major Revision</th>
   <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.document.documentStatus.documentRevision.MajorRevision)</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
   <th>Minor Revision</th>
   <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.document.documentStatus.documentRevision.MinorRevision)</td>
</tr>
</div>
<div id="AlphanumRevision">
   <tr>
      <th>Alphanumeric Revision</th>
      <td>@Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.document.documentStatus.documentRevision.Revision )</td>
   </tr>
</div>
```

...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   //Initial state of the form
   $("#AlphanumRevision").css("display","none");

   // Add onclick handler to checkbox w/id "checkme"
   $("#checkme").click(function(){
      // If checked
      if ($("#checkme").is(":checked")){
       $("#AlphanumRevision").show("fast");
           $("#NumericRevision").hide("fast");
       }
       else {
       $("#AlphanumRevision").hide("fast");
           $("#NumericRevision").show("fast");
    }
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for turning me on to jQuery.  I think I'm in love.  Here's the code that I got to work:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("tr.alpha").hide();
        $("#revision").click(function()
        {
        if($("#numericRevision").is("checked"))
            {
             $("tr.alpha").hide("fast");
             $("tr.numeric").show("fast");
             }
          else
            {
            $("tr.alpha").show("fast");
            $("tr.numeric").hide("fast");
            }
        });
    });
             
</script>